# How can I discover and crawl all of the websites on a webserver?

Tags: web-server

I want to query several *internal* servers that I know are running webservers and discover which websites they are running.  Is it possible to do this?  The servers I need to query are running either Apache, nginx, or IIS.

For example:

```
server1.example.com
  - Using a web browser, this FQDN resolves to www.subsite.com
  - I know there is more than one website hosted here

server2.example.com
  - Using a web browser, this FQDN resolves to www.subsite2.com
  - I know there is more than one website hosted here

...
```

Comment: Not if they're configured correctly.

Comment: Ask the server admins?